# Invoke nested child method using refs reactJS WithStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-with-styles

I am trying to access a method in a nested chilld component using refs. This is to delete data in the nested delete component. My code is as follows (simplified code):

**Parent Class:**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.childref = React.createRef()
    props.refs(this)
  }
  render() {
    const elements = return [
     <div onclick={this.callsupprimer(0)} />,
     <div onclick={this.callsupprimer(1)} />
    ]
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Child refs={ref => this.childref = ref>
        </Child>
       loadToolData()
     </Fragment>
     )
  }
  callsupprimer = index => this.childRef.GrandChildRef.supprimer(index)
}
 export withStyles(styles)(Parent)
```

**Child Class:**

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.grandchildref = React.createRef()
    props.refs(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GrandChild refs={ref => this.grandchildref = ref>
      </GrandChild>
    )
  }
}
 export withStyles(styles)(Child)
```

**GrandChild Class:**

```
class GrandChild extends Component {

  supprimer = (index) => {
        console.log(index)
        this.forceUpdate()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //blah blah blah
    )
  }
}
export withStyles(styles)(GrandChild)
```

However, I cannot get the supprimer method to invoke changes in the this context of GrandChild. The method gets called but, in a strange way.

it gets called once when the component is loaded and prints the index, but it does not work onlick!!!
I don't even call this method in the grandChild class. Please help.

**UPDATE**: The code is exactly as written except for the method names now.

Comment: Shouldn't componentDidUPdate(= be componentDidUpdate()? :P

Comment: ^^ thank you, corrected, but that's not the issue, i just hand wrote this code here, to explain the idea

Comment: You need to call the ref function in the GrandChild constructor with this `props.ref(this)`, Then you will be able access GrandChild from parent using childref

Comment: react tells me: `TypeError: props.ref is not a function`

Comment: Your error by the way look more like a binding issue..

Comment: I tried props.ref = this too, and  now it's like  `Cannot set property ref of #<Object> which has only a getter`. I don't get it, I have used arrow functions for everything, so I shouldn't have to bind any functions right?

Comment: it is correct, you need to pass the child to the ref.

Comment: try to pass `this.childref` insted of `ref => this.childref = ref`

Comment: I tried it too, but `current` becomes undefined when i do that

Comment: I solved the issue in part, problem was that , I was using withstyles, and it passes refs in a different way,  now its about calling the method. Sorry i didn't add that part in the initial question.

Comment: @alexr89 would you mind removing the duplicate tag now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was invoking the `callsupprimer` when rendering, when it should have been done only `onClick`, so the method was called once on rendering and it didn't work after.
Once I changed the `onClick` in the parent class to an arrow function callback:

```
<div onclick={() => this.callsupprimer(1)} />
```

it worked as expected.

**NB**: when using `withstyles`, you need to use refs, and not ref, and then bind the this in the child component as in the question. I didn't need to use `current`. @Hai Alaluf 's comments in the question pointed me in the right way!